# Can the number of suggestions in firefox's location bar be increased?

Tags: firefox

Example : you start typing the address in firefox's location bar, it gives out, uhmm, 6 suggestions. Can that number be increased (also, can it give only the title, without the actual address to save space) ?

Comment: No, it gives out 12. Did you mean that you want to increase the size of the dropdown that shows up?

Comment: @Ignacio - Yes, well, both, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of results returned can be changed with the `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults` config option. The size and format of the actual box can be changed by modifying the browser chrome, but I'm not sure what needs to be changed.

Comment: Never mind. This will do nicely for now. Thanks Ignacio!